# How to print all the staticTexts in XCUITest

Tags: ios, swift, xcuitest

I have used `app.staticTexts["String"].tap()` to tap on a button containing that string which is working completely fine.
But the problem here is that i want to print all the `static` texts which are present on that page, how can i do it in `XCUITest` ?
My aim here is to iterate through all the `static` texts present on the page and then add an `if` condition on my expected text.

Comment: you can try to find all accessibility elemtns and iterate, check XCUIElementQuery. But what you want to do looks more like unit test than UITest,

Comment: @Lu_  I actually want to iterate through all the static texts present on the page and then i would be adding a `if` condition on the expected text. So how can i perform that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use something like that:

```
    for staticText in app.staticTexts.allElementsBoundByIndex {
        if staticText.label == "test" {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Returns all the labels,buttons, textfield,images in the page with its  name.
//Just change the element name in loop according to the need.




 for staticText in  app.staticTexts.allElementsBoundByIndex{

            if staticText != nil{
                print(staticText.label)
            }else{
                print("No static text found")
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the text is present in the `identifier` attribute of the `staticText` element. You can try the following

```
for i in 0..<app.staticTexts.count {
    let text = app.staticTexts.element(boundBy: i).identifier
    print(text)
    if text == "Your String" {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

Comment: Its printing "Find the StaticText" string for every loop, though i want the staticText value

Comment: Instead of `identifier`, try with `value`, `label`,  or `title`